# Imaginary zeros of quasipolynomial

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems, roots, inverse-problems, delay-differential-equations

In the context of DDEs of the type, $$\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t),x(t-\tau_1), ..., x(t-\tau_N)),$$
I am interested in the following question:

For a fixed N, but arbitrary $\tau_n>0$ and $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$, how many distinct imaginary roots can the following quasipolynomial have?
$$h(s) = s - a_0 - \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e^{-s\tau_n} = 0 \qquad (\star)$$

I found a statement (without proof) that for any $\{s_m := i\omega_m\}_{m=1}^{2N-1}$ (counting only $\omega_m>0$) we can find appropriate delays $\tau_n$ and coefficients $a_n$ such that the $\{s_m\}$ are zeros of $(\star)$.

This would mean that we can always find $\tau_n>0$ and $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that,
$$i\omega_m = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e^{-i\omega_m \tau_n}\qquad ,\forall m=1,...,M=2N-1. \quad (\star\star)  $$

While this is obviously true for $N=1$, I could not yet reproduce it for $N>1$. Am I missing something here?

A much weaker result I could derive is that for $N=2M$ and $\omega_m = m \omega, m=1,...,M$ and $\tau_n = \frac{2\pi n}{\omega (M+1)}, n=1,...,N$ we can find coefficients $a_n$ such that $(\star)$ holds. The idea here is that for our choice of $\omega_m, \tau_n\quad(\star\star)$ can be seen as the discrete fourier transform (DFT) of the signal $a_n$. Then using the inverse DFT we get,
$$(a_0, ..., a_N) = DFT^{-1} (0, i\omega_1, ... i\omega_M, -i\omega_M, ..., -i\omega_1). $$
Where the complex conjugate symmetric fourier transform signal is needed to ensure that all $a_n$ are real numbers.

I would be really glad about any hints whether the former statement is true for $M = 2N-1$ or even for $M=N$, which intuitively seems a bit more reasonable to me.

Thanks in advance!

By the way: In order to be more specific, I have completely rewritten this question. I hope that is ok.

Comment: I would say that the best reference is the one that you mention, for this type of questions. You may find useful the more recent book H. Smith, An introduction to delay differential equations with applications to the life sciences, Texts in Applied Mathematics 57, Springer, 2011 (see Chapter 4).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look at it.